# Query Google sheet, format column text to number in data selection before Select

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a query in which I can convert some data from text to numbers, here is what i've done for now :

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE('Input'!D:S;"\.";","))); "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col13, Col16 WHERE Col13 = 'NET A PAYER' ";1)`

This is perfect for changing dot to commas for locale. But when I'm trying to SUM(Col16), this is not working because format of Col16 is text. And I can't CNUM, TO_PURE_NUMBER, *1 because of range where regexreplace is applied. I understand that it's applied for D to S, but I only want it on S.

So, here is my request ! Is it possible within data selection to do something like `=QUERY('Input'!D:ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(S;"\.";",")*1)); "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col13, Col16, SUM(Col16) WHERE Col13 = 'NET A PAYER' ORDER BY Col13 ";1)`

Here is some data test accessible : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vt1dDHzRPwP2tuL5bsqjaE9TJHwL469OddzSeRKk4jU/edit?usp=sharing

I'm hard stuck on it...!
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you share an example within your locale ?

Comment: Done, edited message ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=QUERY({A:C \ ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(D:D;".";",")*1)}; "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col1 = 'NET A PAYER' label Col4 'Gain' ";1)
```

or to do the summing in the query directly

```
=QUERY({A:C \ ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(D:D;".";",")*1)}; "select Col1, Col2, Col3, sum(Col4) WHERE Col1 = 'NET A PAYER' group by Col1, Col2, Col3 label sum(Col4) 'Gain' ";1)
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Can't upvote, I need more reputation but this was very helpful !